# Cart Creation And store_id via REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm fairly new to Magento API (REST) and am trying to create a cart for an existing customer via admin API, update the cart and apply a discount coupon.

So far I've hit two major issues:

1) I can't figure out how to get a clear shopping cart for the user. I'm using the admin API to call `POST` `/all/V1/carts/mine` with `{"customer_id": 4}` (for example) in the body. This returns `8`, which is great and calling `GET` `/all/V1/carts/8` or `GET` `/all/V1/carts/mine?customer_id=4` will get me the cart. The issue is that the cart may already contain some items. Is there a quick way to clear the cart? The obvious thing is to call `DELETE` on all the items in the cart, but one needs to also remember to clear shipping, coupons, etc. This seems to be a similar issue to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7107 There doesn't seem to be a way to delete the entire cart and start over - is there?

2) Having the cart, how do I change the `store_id` of the cart? I've tried virtually everything (`PUT` request onto `/all/V1/carts/8` with `{"store_id": 1}` and various variations, most of them ending in error that the request is missing `customer_id` and with `customer_id` an error `The customer can't be assigned to the cart because the cart isn't anonymous.`), but it still says `store_id: 0`. The issue is that when I try to add a coupon to that cart using `PUT` `/all/V1/carts/8/coupons/20OFF`, I get an error `Cart isn't assigned to correct store`. This happens for all the coupons. The scope of the coupon is the website.

Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please review all detail with an example in the rest API swagger.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure if you are asking me to supply specific API calls, or if you are just referring me to the docs as I've gone through them quite a few times and am unable to get past the issues I've mentioned...